# Show that measure is zero when satisfy following condition

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $ \mu $ be a borel measure on [0,1]. Suppose that integral (over [0,1] )of $x^{n}$ is zero with respect to that measure for each non negative integer n. How to show that $ \mu = 0 $

Comment: Use Weierstrass Approximation Theorem to yield the integral of any continuous function with respect to $\mu$ is zero.

Comment: $\mu([0,1])=\int x^0\,d\mu$